# How solar and lunar longitudes can be calculated for tithi calculation

Tags: vedas, panchang

For tithi calculations, we have to derive solar longitude and lunar longitudes first.
Then only we can calculate tithi in [Panchangam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchangam).

Could you please help me to find solar longitude and lunar longitude for [Panchangam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchangam)

Comment: That's not a one line formula.  It may cover one full textbook length of explanations and reference tables.  For your interest, please refer [this](https://www.tifr.res.in/~archaeo/papers/Astronomy%20and%20Sanskrit%20literature/Tithi%20calculations.pdf) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_of_the_Sun)

Comment: thank you so much @AnilGoyal sir

Comment: Call me Anil :). If you can read in hindi, I know there is a book published by MotilalBanarasiDas on these planetary longitudinal calculations for vedic astrology.  I read that book.  But in this computer era, these long and tiring calculations are not so much used.  Still if you want I can find the name of that book.